Raising a dialog window from a Windows .sys driver from the command line?
I would like to allow the user of my application to directly open the (Windows Control Panel) "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)" properties dialog (see image below), for a selected network connection; and to do that, I first have to ensure that I can do the same from the Windows 10 command line (either cmd.exe or PowerShell).
This is basically the same as asked in this question:

windows 7 - how to open tcp/ip properties from cmd or run directly? - Super User

... except I have slightly more details in this question, so I hope I can get a more conclusive answer than:

There is no way to open up that specific property window directly. There's only a shortcut to the "generic" interfaces screen, being ncpa.cpl.

... so I can get some closure on this issue.
Note that I am not interested in how to change network connection settings from the command line (the cited question already has an answer for that). I am also not interested in looking up open windows, and sending virtual keyboard presses/keystrokes to it (the cited question already has an AutoKey answer; although one could also Get a list of all open windows from the command line  and then send keys to an active window in Powershell)
I think I can reduce this specific issue, to how to raise a dialog window from a Windows driver .sys file. But first of all, let me go through the procedure, of what I can do from the command line so far. Most of this comes from the cited post.
First of all, we can query the registry for actual network cards; here is what I get in cmd.exe on my Windows 10 machine:
C:\tmp>reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkCards"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkCards\5
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkCards\6

So, I have network interface cards (NICs) 5 and 6. Let's query NIC 6 for its GUID, which is given as ServiceName:
C:\tmp>reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkCards\6"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkCards\6
    ServiceName    REG_SZ    {80CD6CC2-1673-4BBB-A561-C219841EE3A9}
    Description    REG_SZ    Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V

Ok, so the GUID of my NIC 6, which is "Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V", is {80CD6CC2-1673-4BBB-A561-C219841EE3A9}.
Then, from https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/CLSID-List.htm I can see:



CLSID
Location
Availability




::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}
Network Connections
XP-11



... that the CLSID of the (Control Panel) Network Connections window is ::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}.
Finally, I can append the GUID of the network NIC/adapter with a backslash to the CLSID of the Network Connection window, and run this in cmd.exe:
start ::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}\{80CD6CC2-1673-4BBB-A561-C219841EE3A9}

... and I get the Ethernet Status dialog shown on the image below left:

From the Ethernet Status dialog window I still have to click Properties to give administrator permissions - then I get the Ethernet Properties window. On the Ethernet properties window, I have to scroll and find the "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)" entry, then double-click it - and after that, I finally get the "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) Properties" dialog window.
Restating this, just to make it clear: what I want to do, is to run a command on the command line, and get to the "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) Properties" of this (Ethernet) connection directly (without intermediary windows that I have to click).
Now, I've tried looking through my Windows Registry for the "TCP/IPv4" string, and there are these two entries:

Computer\HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Classes\Local Settings\MuiCache\a39\52C64B7E
Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software\Classes\Local Settings\MuiCache\a39\52C64B7E

... both of which have:

key: @%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys,-10100
value: Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)

AFAIK, .sys files in Windows are driver files, that have their own restrictions (though I do not know these restrictions exactly); so tcpip.sys must be the TCP/IP Windows driver.
Then, it seems tcpip.sys accepts an argument, in this case -10100, which seems to denote TCP/IPv4 -- it is noticeable in the registry, that for instance the argument -10102 denotes TCP/IPv6.
So, apparently, the "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) Properties" comes somehow from tcpip.sys, set up with the argument -10100 to target TCP/IPv4 ; but also somehow setup with the GUID of the target network connection, here {80CD6CC2-1673-4BBB-A561-C219841EE3A9}, that we want to view the properties of.
So, my question is: is there a way to raise/open the dialog window of a Windows driver file, here tcpip.sys, from the command line (cmd.exe or PowerShell), while specifying arguments (here -10100 for TCP/IPv4, and {80CD6CC2-1673-4BBB-A561-C219841EE3A9} for the target network adapter/connection)?
If not directly from the command line, are there any APIs that would allow me to do this in e.g. VBScript, or C/C++ from Visual Studio, that I can look up/consult?
